# What are Fourier Pairs?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

Given Fourier's Inversion theorem:
$$f(t)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\omega =-\infty}^\infty e^{i \omega t} \, \mathrm{d}\omega \int_{u=-\infty}^\infty f(u) e^{-i\omega u} \,\mathrm{d}u  \tag{1}$$
and the Fourier transform of $f(t)$:
$$\displaystyle\mathcal{F}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}\color{red}{f(t)}e^{-i\omega t}\mathrm{d}t\tag{A}$$

and the Inverse Fourier transform of $\mathcal{F}(\omega)$:

$$\displaystyle \color{red}{f(t)}=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\omega=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}(\omega)e^{i\omega t}\mathrm{d}\omega}\tag{B}$$

In trying to understand Fourier pairs I substitute $(\mathrm{B})$ into $(\mathrm{A})$ by replacing the part marked $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ in  $(\mathrm{A})$ with the expression  $(\mathrm{B})$ which gives

$$\displaystyle\mathcal{F}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\omega=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}(\omega)e^{i\omega t}\mathrm{d}\omega}e^{-i\omega t}\mathrm{d}t$$

$$\implies \mathcal{F}(\omega)=\color{#180}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{\omega=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}(\omega)\mathrm{d}\omega \mathrm{d}t}\tag{C}$$

Now unless I'm mistaken the RHS of $(\mathrm{C})$ marked $\color{#180}{\mathrm{green}}$ should reduce to $\mathcal{F}(\omega)$ on the LHS of $(\mathrm{C})$.

What steps do I need to take to show this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be slightly more careful with your notation. We have the Fourier transform
$$
 \hat{f}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-i\omega x} \,dx
$$
and Fourier inversion
$$
 f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\xi) e^{i\xi x} \,d\xi.
$$
You want to insert the first equation into the second:
$$
  \hat{f}(\omega) =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\xi) e^{-i\omega x} e^{i\xi x} \,d\xi\,dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\xi) e^{i(\xi - \omega)x} \,d\xi\,dx
$$
The thing to realize is that the $\omega$ appearing in the argument of $\hat{f}$ on the left is *not* the same as the one that appears in the definition of the Fourier inversion (your Equation B). By using different letters for the dummy integration variables, you see that the exponentials do not cancel, and the correct version of your equation (C) is the one I have above. At this step there is not much else that can be simplified. Rather than thinking of simplifying your green equation (or, rather, the corrected version I propose), think of it as a result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if the Fourier transform is a transformation of $f(t)$ then the Fourier inversion is a transformation of ...?

Comment: Well, it is (almost the same) transformation applied to $\hat{f}(\omega)$, namely it is a transform of the Fourier transform of $f$. I'm not sure that this is mathematically meaningful though.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why you said "You should be slightly more careful with your notation."?

Comment: @Andrew In your last integral the $x$-integration leads to the delta function $δ(ξ-ω)$ and you get the left hand side back.

Comment: @Urgje Would you mind showing the steps to get to recover the LHS?

Comment: @Andrew "The thing to realize is that the $\omega$ appearing in the argument of $\hat f$ on the left is not the same as the one that appears in the definition of the Fourier inversion (your Equation B)". Why are the $\omega$'s not the same?

Comment: @Urgje you're totally right, but I actually view my argument as justification for why that integral is the delta function. So, I left it out so as to not be circular.

Comment: @BLAZE I'll answer your other questions at the same time. I mean you should be more careful because the $\omega$ on the LHS is different than the one that appears as the dummy integration variable. I think the best way to think about it is through analogy. Think about the FTC. You would write $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\, dt$, but not $\int_a^x f(x)\,dx$, even though we want to think of these as functions of $x$, like $F(x)$ and $f(x)$. In order to avoid confusion we change the integration dummy variable to a new letter because they aren't the same.

Comment: @Andrew Okay thanks

Comment: @Andrew "I'll answer your other questions at the same time". Well?

Comment: @BLAZE which question did not get a clear answer? Notation was not using the same variable for two things in the same equation, and different $\omega$s for the reason I stated above.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your excellent answer, sorry I was unable to reply before. Just _one_ more quick question: If the $\omega$'s are different then  why are they not denoted differently say $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$?

Comment: @BLAZE I am not sure which ones you are talking about. I wrote my formulae so that any $\omega$ that appears is the same. To avoid confusion, I did not use the symbol $\omega $ in my equation defining Fourier Inversion. I used a different symbol, $\xi$. Writing $\omega_2$ instead of $\xi$ would also be acceptable. But to be clear, each $\omega$ you see in my equations is the same. In my response I was referring to your $\omega$s, meaning the $\omega$ in eq. A being used as an input variable is not the same as the $\omega$ you used in eq. B that appears as a dummy integration variable.

Comment: @Andrew I was referring to these $\omega$'s in the integrand: $\displaystyle\mathcal{F}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\omega=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathcal{F} (\omega) e^{i\omega t}\mathrm{d}\omega}e^{-i\omega t}\mathrm{d}t$

Comment: @BLAZE  they arent the same for the reason I described above. One $\omega$ appears as an input variable, one appears as a dummy integration variable. These are literally two different things.

Comment: @Andrew Okay thanks again, you've been of massive help to me